# Add video file in debut theme product page

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-template

I am working on the debut theme of Shopify. here I have added the custom code of product images.

```html
<div class="product-image-left single-itemim lightbox-pop Mobile"> 
              
               {% if product.images.size > 0 %}
              {% for image in product.images %} 
              {% capture wrapper_class %}
              {%- unless featured_image == image -%}
              hide
              {%- endunless -%}
              {% endcapture %}
              <div data-index="{{ forloop.index }}" id="ImageWrapper-{{ image.id }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" class="responsive-image__wrapper" {{ wrapper_attributes }}>
                 <a href="{{ image | img_url: '1000x' }}" class="image-popup-link"><img id="Image-{{ image.id }}"
                     class="responsive-image__image lazyload {{ image_class }}"
                     src="{{ image | img_url: '800x' }}"
                     data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                     data-widths="[{{ image_widths }}]"
                     data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
                     data-sizes="auto"
                     tabindex="-1"
                     alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"
                     {{ image_attributes }}
                     >
                </a>  
               
              </div>

              {% endfor %}
            {%else%}
            <div class="responsive-image__wrapper ">
           {{ 'image' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
            {%endif%}         
            </div>
```

Can some one here help. to tell how can I add the video file code here.So I can add all format video files.Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

There's already a tutorial for it on Shopify's page.

See here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-theme-support-for-rich-media-3d-and-video

EDIT:
You should replace your whole code that you posted above with

```
{% for media in product.media %}
  {% include 'media' %}
{% endfor %}
```

And then move your code to **media.liquid** snippet like this:

```
{% case media.media_type %}
  {% when 'image' %}
    <div class="product-image-left single-itemim lightbox-pop Mobile">
        {% if product.images.size > 0 %}
            {% for image in product.images %}
            {% capture wrapper_class %}
            {%- unless featured_image == image -%}
            hide
            {%- endunless -%}
            {% endcapture %}
            <div data-index="{{ forloop.index }}" id="ImageWrapper-{{ image.id }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" class="responsive-image__wrapper" {{ wrapper_attributes }}>
                <a href="{{ image | img_url: '1000x' }}" class="image-popup-link"><img id="Image-{{ image.id }}"
                                                                                       class="responsive-image__image lazyload {{ image_class }}"
                                                                                       src="{{ image | img_url: '800x' }}"
                                                                                       data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                                                                                       data-widths="[{{ image_widths }}]"
                                                                                       data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
                                                                                       data-sizes="auto"
                                                                                       tabindex="-1"
                                                                                       alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"
                                                                                       {{ image_attributes }}
                >
                </a>

            </div>

            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="responsive-image__wrapper ">
                {{ 'image' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% when 'external_video' %}
    <div class="product-single__media" style="padding-top: {{ 1 | divided_by: media.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%;" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
      {{ media | external_video_tag }}
    </div>
  {% when 'video' %}
    <div class="product-single__media" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
      {{ media | video_tag: controls: true }}
    </div>
  {% when 'model' %}
    <div class="product-single__media" style="padding-top: 100%" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
      {{ media | model_viewer_tag }}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="product-single__media" style="padding-top: 100%;" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
      {{ media | media_tag }}
    </div>
{% endcase %}
```

Comment: Yes i have used this doc, but it is showing image slider and video slider. on mobile all to gether

Comment: can you please tell, where in the above code I need to include "media snippet"

Comment: Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag ' <else></else>', It is showing this error on snippet, while trying to save it

Comment: Oops, my editor corrected it when pasting the code, just need to change `{% <else></else>%}` to `{% else %}`

Comment: https://p3y09jqqjdx5lmdh-45950501019.shopifypreview.com/collections/room_collection/products/inka-arne-dining-chair, please check this link on mobile version

Comment: This is the pw: aichay

Comment: Is there a reason you're using separate sliders for mobile and desktop? My suggestion would be just to get rid of the mobile version all together and just use the desktop version on mobile as well. You're unnecessary loading both of them.

Comment: instead of media.liquidsnippet, i am using mediamobile.liquid snippet, do i have to make any change in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220605/discussion-between-rahul-dogra-and-sean-s).

Comment: Hi i have updated the code, but I am still having little issue

Comment: https://inka-corps.myshopify.com/collections/room_collection/products/inka-arne-dining-chair